# Batch File to Adjust Registry with Contents of Text File

Tags: batch-file, passwords, registry

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

I'd like an end-user to be able to type their updated AD password into a Text file, then run a Batch which adjusts the registry with the user's updated AD Password to configure Auto-Login to Windows. After the Registry is updated, I'd like the contents of the Text file cleared.

The purpose of this is so users can re-configure their Auto-Logon themselves after they change their passwords (which expire every 90-days in my environment).

How can I pull the text out of the Text file and apply it to a Reg key? Alternatively, is there a way that the Batch file can simply prompt for their new password, so I can avoid using the Text file all together?

Thanks in advance,
Cameron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like the following. It prompts for the password, rather than using the text file. It also uses the current logged in user name. ***Please note that this stores the users domain password in clear-text in the registry where anyone with access to the machine can read it. This is VERY insecure, though there can be reasons to use it. I would offer my opinion that if you're doing this with domain passwords, this is probably the wrong thing to do.***

```
@Echo off
setlocal

set /p PWD= Enter your password: 

reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /f /v DefaultUserName /t REG_SZ /d %USERNAME%
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /f /v DefaultPassword /t REG_SZ /d %PWD%
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /f /v AutoAdminLogon /t REG_SZ /d 1

endlocal
```